# Project files in KDevelop

Tags: c++, linux, kdevelop

I am trying to use KDevelop to write a cmake based simple application. KDevelop created two  myProject.kdev4 project files: one in the project folder and one in .kdev4 hidden subfolder. Both are non-empty. Which ones should I check in? How can I make kdevelop use just one project file (and preferably not use hidden folders)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .kdev4 file is used for kdevelop specific information (It mainly only tells KDevelop to use the CMake project manager). The folder includes user specific configuration (If you are familiar with Visual Studio, it is like the .user files).

Usually only the CMakeLists.txt files are needed as they should have all the relevant generic data. You can throw in the .kdev4 file so that you don't need to 'import' the project through the CMakeLists.txt on another machine. But the .kdev4 folder should stay in your local machine, as you don't want to mix user's configurations.